# Methods to generate 100 kHz SPWM

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, inverter, h-bridge

I am trying to generate a 100 kHz SPWM signal to drive a single-phase H-bridge inverter. Currently, I am using an STMF32F4 and a look-up table in software to generate this signal without very good results.

I was wondering if this would be the best way to do this and if it is just a problem with the code, or if it is a hardware problem.

From my understanding, the STMF32F4 should have a high enough clock speed to generate a 100 kHz signal. If you know of other and better methods to do this (that are also less expensive than using a DDS function generator) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using timers and PWM?  Not sure about upper frequency.  I can check later this week.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Mostly because the SPWM implementation using a microcontroller and software seemed simpler. If you have any resources I can check out in doing this using timers and PWM that would be great.

Comment: @rdtsc Correct me if I am wrong, but common methods online that I have seen to implement a DC-AC H-bridge inverter use as sinusoidal pwm signal to drive the mosfets. I apologize if this is wrong, but if it is possible to drive with traditional PWM to get a sinusoidal output would you send me a resource that could point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: A pure SPWM needs so much more MIPS than a software controlled hardware PWM. Use the peripherals of your MCU. I'm sure there are many tutorials about the matter, but it is your task to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [STM32F4](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f4-series.html) should be more than powerful enough for a DC-AC inverter at over 200MIPS.  But consider specializing; some chips have features which could be useful for this specific application.

What you want to do is use a hardware PWM peripheral and implement something like this pseudo-code:

- Set a hardware (interrupt) timer for the modulation frequency of interest, say 10kHz.  \$\frac{1}{10\text{kHz}}\$ = 100µs.
- Build once and store as a table, sine values for an entire cycle at your modulation frequency.
- - Start timer, begin loop.
- - Fetch first value from the table and output to PWM peripheral.
- - Increment value index pointer, so it now points to the next value.
- - If this pointer is >= sizeof(table), then set the pointer back to the first entry.
- - Wait for the timer to expire, then loop.

This might work ok with no load applied.  But apply a load, and the waveform will likely distort. Most AC devices tolerate distortion well.  Could sample this and use it to alter behavior, but that quickly becomes a very advanced topic.  Take a look at this [Microchip Reference Design](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/solutions/power-management-and-conversion/intelligent-power/dc-to-ac-power-inverter-solutions) and related documents to see how they implemented it. Note, they used specialized DSC's (digital signal controllers.)

Comment: I appreciate the reply, I will look into both options. I will continue tweaking the SPWM from the MCU to make it work for now and will get into specializing once I get an SPWM to test out the inverter circuit I have. Thanks

Comment: @ rdtsc Just an update, I have been able to generate the SPWM signal I need through the STM32F4 and I am now looking to add dead-time. If I am not allowed to ask for extra info in the same post please forgive me. Currently, I am using Schmitt triggers and an RC circuit to do this with good results. I have also looked at software implementations. From my understanding, hardware should be the way to go as it will be faster and more reliable. Am I correct? I have looked online for comparisons between the two and have not gotten any concrete opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd personally recommend dedicated gate-driver chips.  These make it easier for you by (most) incorporating dead-time and high-side gate drive.  Gate drivers are design-able discretely, but takes a fair amount of effort and there are many pitfalls that only become apparent when debugging improper operation.